# How to build a regular expression which makes every first letter of the word capital in SAP HANA?

Tags: expression, hana

How to build a regular expression which makes every first letter of the word capital ?

I tried using this :

```
select Upper(LEFT('this iS hana',1)) || lower(right(('this iS hana'), 
                               length('this iS hana')-1)) FROM DUMMY;
```

This gives me the result :

> This is hana.

whereas what I want to achieve is :

> This Is Hana.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, you cannot achieve this using regular expressions in SAP HANA. Normally with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE) you would be able to do something like:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE_REGEXPR('\b(\w)(\w+)' 
    IN 'your string here' WITH '\U\1\E\2') FROM DUMMY;
```

And HANA apparently supports PCRE, so it should theoretically work based on the [REPLACE_REGEXPR](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/dcf1045ce51d45119cfe8ba17cf9da4f.html) documentation:

> pattern ::= !!Perl Compatible Regular Expression
>
> A search pattern based on Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE).

Unfortunately, the `\U` and `\E` constructs seem to not be implemented in HANA.

The good news is that since HANA2 SP01, there is a new string function that can achieve roughly what you need: [INITCAP](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.01/en-US/d1e67902534d426180459ae45a264667.html). Note that this also changes the rest of the letters from inside the words to lowercase:

> Converts the first character of each word in a specified string to uppercase and converts remaining characters to lowercase.

So you can just do:

```sql
SELECT INITCAP('your string here') FROM DUMMY;
```